# Getting a 500 Internal server error when redirecting to the callback url using google OAuth2 with Passportjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

The app credentials seem fine. The redirected URL brings back the profile object with 500 Internal server error. Due to this any code inside the get callback route does not work. Any help will be appreciated.

Here are snippets of my code:

```
app.post('/auth/google', checkNotAuthenticated, passport.authenticate('google', {
  scope: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
}))

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: process.env.GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    return done(profile.id);
  }

app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', { successRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  // code does not work
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

The callback done accepts two arguments instead of one. So, in the `return` statement of the `passport.use()` will be `done(null, profile.id)`.